# Pandas sum for the rest of month

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks this:

```
import pandas as pd

date = ['28-01-2017','29-01-2017','30-01-2017','31-01-2017','01-02-2017','02-02-2017','...']
sales = [1,2,3,4,1,2,'...']
days_left_in_m = [3,2,1,0,29,28,'...']
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'date': date,'days_left_in_m':days_left_in_m,'sales':sales})

df_test
```

I am trying to find sales for the rest of the month.

So, for 28th of Jan 2017 it will calculate sum of the next 3 days,
for 29th of Jan - sum of the next 2 days and so on...

The outcome should look like the "required" column below.

```
       date    days_left_in_m   sales   required
0   28-01-2017     3              1        10
1   29-01-2017     2              2        9
2   30-01-2017     1              3        7
3   31-01-2017     0              4        4
4   01-02-2017     29             1        3
5   02-02-2017     28             2        2
6   ...           ...            ...      ...
```

My current solution is really ugly - I use a non-pythonic looping:

```
for i in range(lenght_of_t_series):

        days_left = data_in.loc[i].days_left_in_m

        if days_left == 0:

            sales_temp_list.append(0)
        else:
            if (i+days_left) <= lenght_of_t_series:

                sales_temp_list.append(sum(data_in.loc[(i+1):(i+days_left)].sales))    
            else:
                sales_temp_list.append(np.nan)
```

I guess a much better way of doing this would be to use `df['sales'].rolling(n).sum()`
However, each row has a different window.

Please advise on the best way of doing this...

Comment: Your dataframe and your outcome looks the same.

Comment: Thanks - made it more clear. I was after the "required" column

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html).
If you do not want to take into account the current day you can
 use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) (see commented code).

First you could convert date column to `datetime` in order to use [`Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html)

```
df_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'],format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

---

Then we can use:

```
months = df_test['date'].dt.month
df_test['required'] = (df_test.sort_values('date',ascending = False)
                              .groupby(months)['sales'].cumsum()
                             #.groupby(months).shift(fill_value = 0)
                        )
print(df_test)
```

**Output**

```
        date  days_left_in_m  sales  required
0 2017-01-28               3      1        10
1 2017-01-29               2      2         9
2 2017-01-30               1      3         7
3 2017-01-31               0      4         4
4 2017-02-01              29      1         3
5 2017-02-02              28      2         2
```

---

If you don't want convert `date` column to `datetime` use:

```
months = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'],format = '%d-%m-%Y').dt.month
df_test['required'] = (df_test.sort_values('date',ascending = False)
                              .groupby(months)['sales'].cumsum()
                             #.groupby(months).shift(fill_value = 0)
                        )
```